# Calculations across excel sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dax

I am having problem with the following code.

I am trying to copy some data (as values) from one sheet to another (the data in the original sheet ("DAX NE3") is retrieved from a DAX database and the number of rows may vary depending on the date etc., so it has to copy all rows in every case). I have to take the two first columns (A and B) in "DAX NE3" and copy into column A and B in "Sheet4", but column C-F in "DAX NE3" has to be copied to column D-G in "Sheet4". All blank cells in the original data has to be equal to '0'. Furthermore I need to make a 'Share of part' in column C in 'Sheet4', so example C6=B6/sum(all B) and so on.

My Data when copying and pasting is all over the place. Can someone see why and please help?

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim m As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim result As Variant
Dim firstvalue As Variant
Dim secondvalue As Variant

'Delete old data
Worksheets("Sheet4").Rows("6:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents


'Copy data from one sheet to another
On Error Resume Next
m = Worksheets("DAX NE3").Range("A:B").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
If Err Then
    MsgBox "No data to copy!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Worksheets("DAX NE3").Range("A27:C" & m).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A6:C" & m + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A6:C" & m + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("DAX NE3").Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A6").Resize(m)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

On Error Resume Next
m = Worksheets("DAX NE3").Range("B:F").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
If Err Then
    MsgBox "No data to copy!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Worksheets("DAX NE3").Range("B27:G" & m).Copy
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C6:G" & m + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C6:G" & m + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Worksheets("DAX NE3").Range("C1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C6").Resize(m)
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Change all Blank cells to '0'
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B6:B" & m)
Sheets("Sheet4").Activate
rng.Select
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

'Calculate Share of portfolio %
firstvalue = Range("B6").Value
secondvalue = Range("B6" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value > 0
m = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("C6:C" & m).Formula = firstvalue / secondvalue

End Sub
```

Comment: `m` holds the number of rows you have on the source worksheet and is used extensively. Yet your first `Copy` statement only starts copying from row 27, so `m` will be 26 too high at that point. But you then paste that data to row 6 onwards, so when it inserts, it'll include a load of empty rows. If you run this code on say, 30 rows of random data starting at row 1, stepping through each line with F8, you can see exactly what it's doing..

Comment: That is true. Reason of it starting from row 27 is because the data in "DAX NE3" starts from row 27 and it has to be copied into "Sheet4" from row 6 onwards.